# virtualbox: Set defualt disk size

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

Could I change virtualbox settings in order to change the default disk size?

I mean, I'm setting up my vms using vagrant. I know that, theorycally I'm able to use `vagrant-disksize` and enablings `VAGRANT_EXPERIMENTAL="disks"`. However, they has not able to shrink or decrease disk size from default created `40G` to `requested one`.

My third option is to change VirtualBox settings in order to change the default disk size of any vm.

Any ideas?